# SQL Adapter Authentication - Worklight

Tags: mysql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using adapter authentication in the sample app that I am working on. I needed the login page in the start up, so I have used the `WL.Client.Login` in the js file liek this

function wlCommonInit(){

```
WL.Client.login("AuthRealm", {onSuccess: winFunction, onFailure: failureFunction});
```

}

it calls the  challenger handler and below function is getting invoked

```
$("#AuthSubmitButton").bind('click', function () {
    var username = $("#AuthUsername").val();
    var password = $("#AuthPassword").val();
console.log("called");
    var invocationData = {
        adapter : "Auth",
        procedure : "submitAuthentication",
        parameters : [username,password ]
    };
```

So it goes to the Adapter-impl.js file where I am getting the input like this..

```
var auth = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select * FROM users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ? ;");
function submitAuthentication(username,password){

    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement :auth,
        parameters : [username,password],

    });

}
```

The problem is, it successfully shows the login page on start up and it goes to the adapter file too.. I dont know where can I create useridentity and  `WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity);` as `WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement` not accepting `onsuccess` parameter.

There is no examples available for the Sql adapter authentication for worklight. So I had no option but to ask a question. Please help me with this!

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to just return sql invocation result. On the contrary, use it in your adapter to see whether authentication was successful. e.g.

```
var result = WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement(....);
if (result is not empty) {
     WL.Server.setActiveUser("realm", userIdentity).
     return {authStatus:"success"};
} else
     return {authStatus:"failure"};
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response anton. It`s showing error for the is not even though I declare the result variable as boolean?..

Comment: @Anton WL-AUTHENTICATION-SUCCESS is not present in the result of the protected procedure.Why?